# Expand variable in brace expansion

Tags: bash, variable-substitution, brace-expansion

I am trying to enumerate a range of integers using a variable but having some trouble.  When I type

```
echo {1..5}
```

I get

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

However, when I type a variable, I am unable to get the enumeration.  For example

```
$ num=5
$ echo {1..$num}
{1..5}
```

I am stumped as to why the result is not the same.  I have tried using quotes and that has not helped either.  Can someone help or explain?

Comment: Brace expansion happens *before* variable expansion in bash...

Comment: So, is there a workaround for that?

Comment: You could use `eval`, but there are probably cleaner solutions.

Comment: One other workaround is to use `ksh`.

Comment: The `eval` way: `eval echo \{1..$num\}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this:

```
 num=5;
 echo $(seq $num)
```

Gives:

```
 1 2 3 4 5
```

Remark: `$(...)` syntax is command substitution.

Comment: Or just `seq -s " " $num`, thus avoiding `echo` and subshell expansion.